# ConcurrentHashmap simultaneous write and get operations

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a question about ConcurrentHashMaps. Lets say I have 2 threads.
Thread A tries to get an object from a shared ConcurrentHashMap.
Thread B clears the shared map.
What happens if Thread A and Thread B access the shared resource simultaneously, at the very same time. I searched the documentation and the web and can't find a definitive answer, also tried to do it myself but to no avail.

Comment: SBabach, it's called "Concurrent"HashMap. You cannot access its functionalities simultanously... So that behaviour you ask for will never happen :)

Comment: Note: one thread always goes first because they cannot access the same key simultaneously. You may or may not see the object depending on when operation is performed on that key first.

Comment: The last part sounds mysterious “…also tried to do it myself but to no avail.” Really? There was no result? The map returned Schrödinger's cat all the time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ConcurrentHashMap is divided into different **segments** based on concurrency level. So different threads can access different segments concurrently in java.

> Can threads read the segment of ConcurrentHashMap locked by some other
>   thread in java?

Yes. When thread locks one segment for updation it does not block it for retrieval (done by get method) hence some other thread can read the segment (by get method), but it will be able to read the data before locking.

For operations such as **putAll** concurrent retrievals may reflect removal of only some entries.
For operations such as **clear** concurrent retrievals may reflect removal of only some entries.

Answer (score 2):

There can't be two threads **changing** things at the same time. The whole point of using such data structures is that they **prevent** more than one thread *updating* that "core internal data" at the same time.

Having two threads that change the map at the very same point time is *not* possible. Because the code within that ConcurrentHashMap will not **allow** two threads to manipulate things *in parallel*!

**But**: when **one** thread is *only* reading, and the other is *updating* that data; things are different! As the *reading* part can "enter" the critical section even when it is currently owned by another thread.

Comment: I think (s)he is asking about a `get` and a `remove` at the same time. Javadocs *Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove)*

Comment: There can be two threads changing things at the same time, the goal of `ConcurrentHashMap` is not to prevent it, but to have “_full concurrency of retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates_” such that it keeps the internal structures consistent while providing good performance.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite clear about this case:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove).

So if the two threads use the resource at the same time but one is reading and the other one is updating you could read a resource that is not available.
For more info check the [documentation paragraph 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)