# How can I make sure that write happens before read in concurrenthashmap at the same time by different thread at same bucket and on a same key?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, concurrenthashmap

I want to make sure that while reading and writing at the same bucket and key, the fetched value should be updated, that is it should be fetched after the write operation to it. how can I achieve that ?

What I want is if I update the value for one key and for the same key if I fetch the value with different thread at the same time then I should get the updated value not the previous one, this is what I want to achieve.

I can think of using wait/notify, join to use here before any operation but I am not sure about it.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap provides that guarantee. You font need to write any code to get that guarantee.

Comment: See I am doing read and write at the same time at same bucket with same key. Still will concurrent Hashmap will do write first and then read  ??

Comment: CHM guarantees that all threads that read after the writing thread will see the updated value. If your other thread reads a nanosecond *before* the write, it will see the old value of course. If that is a problem for you, you need to bring some defined order into the two threads doing something "at the same time".

Comment: @Thilo I am doing read and write at the same time, exact same even in nanosecond so I want to make sure that read should be done after write, even two threads are executing at exact same time

Comment: One of them will go first. CHM guarantees that no strange mixup of data will be seen. Only what either serialization of events would have produced. If you need the writer to go first, you have to coordinate between the two threads somehow. If they are "independent", then that is just normal, expected behaviour.

Comment: That coordination you say how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

We all know how concurrent hashmap works if not, here : [ConcurrentHashmap simultaneous write and get operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212950/concurrenthashmap-simultaneous-write-and-get-operations)

According to this article Concurrent hasmap already has that feature, please refer the below  para and link 
Read-Write Operation :- Two threads can read and write data on different segments at the same time without blocking each other. In general, Retrieval operations do not block, so may overlap with write (put/remove) operations. Latest updated value will be returned by get operation which is most recently updated value by write operation (including put/remove)

https://medium.com/@itsromiljain/curious-case-of-concurrenthashmap-90249632d335

PS: I have not tried it, please update me if the above article(curious case) mentioned wrongly.

Comment: I want to use on same bucket and same key, I know concurrenthashmap has the feature to read it, but what i want is if I update the value for one key and for the same I am fetching with different thread at the same time then I should get the updated value not the previous one

Comment: I had read that medium article before posting question, that article does not state about my problem

Comment: your first link states that it will show its previous value but I want to make sure that I see the updated value. so how can i do it ?

Comment: The medium articles says, it will return the updated value if two thread(read and write) arrives at same point at same object, BTW in an interview I argued with with interviewer with same answer as yours, but he he was pretty Sure that read will get updated value not the old value. Need to check that. Thinking aloud, other way you can achieve if the above said things are wrong, you need to building something called thread management,  check if multiple thread arrived at same time has write operation if Yes then assign it with high priority.